# ubuntu acting weird after showing low on space warning

Tags: boot

(this is my first question here, I'm sorry if there is a problem) I installed ubuntu 16.04 lts 3 months ago. Today I was trying to install gtk+-3.0 using `sudo apt install gtk+-3.0` which started to download about 500mb. I came back about 3 hours after that to check on the installation, and I faced a warning indicating I had 0 bytes free on my system, which was weird somehow. I tried to delete some files but I noticed that there was a lock picture next to every icon, and I couldn't change my language to English, in fact, I couldn't change any of the system settings. I restarted the computer and chose ubuntu when the grub menu opened up (I have windows 8 installed) and this time it asked for manual fsck. I did a manual fsck on /dev/sda7 and answered "yes" to all the questions it asked, then I rebooted and this time ubuntu login page showed up(and the selected language was English). I logined and again the "you've got only 0 bytes" warning showed up. I decided to remove some apps so I opened the software center and chose remove for some app. When I was asked for my password, I noticed that my language was changed to Persian and I was unable to change any settings.
I really have no idea why all this happened.

Comment: Phew, that's a lot issues. Is there any way you could get any log files from the system?

Comment: Boot the Ubuntu Live DVD, and start the `Disk Usage Analyser` viewing your primary hard disk to determine which directories might be consuming the most space. Cheers, Al

Comment: I don't know how to get log files from the system, but I'll try to do so. thanks for viewing, Owen Hines :)

Comment: I'm going to try what you said, thanks for your suggestion heynnema :)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to login to my account (luckily the selected language was English when I booted the computer) and managed to free about 11gb on my home directory, and the problem was solved! I could normally change my language and system settings. I still don't know why that manual fsck thing happened. Thanks anyone who viewed this question!